# Producer consumer using blockingqueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have started learning threads and tried Producer consumer problem in Java using concurrent package introduced in JDK 5.0 I have written the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

class Producer implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> objqueue;

    Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> obj) {
    objqueue = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Put : " + i);
            objqueue.put(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        i++;
    }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
private final BlockingQueue<Integer> objqueue;

Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> obj) {
    objqueue = obj;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Got : " + objqueue.take());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

}

public class PCMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create shared object
    BlockingQueue<Integer> obj = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();

    Thread prod = new Thread(new Producer(obj));
    Thread cons = new Thread(new Consumer(obj));

    prod.start();
    cons.start();
}

}
```

The program is not terminating when the producer has produced up to 9 and consumer consumed up to 9. Should I remove the while loop which is true forever in Consumer.

How can I make it for more than one Producer and one Consumer?
Thanks.

Comment: Why should it terminate?

Comment: When producer has stopped producing shouldn't the program terminate?

Comment: Well, I don't see a main method, so we don't know how you are calling this or what you are attempting to stop the code.  But in general, no, it doesn't stop on its own.

Comment: A program stops when ALL non-daemon threads stop running. Not when 1 non-deamon thread stops running.

Comment: I wrote an example for a friend a while back, and I used an `ExecutorService` and an explicit `shutdown()` call, so there's lots of ways to do this.  Hence: need to see main method.

Comment: It has main() in PCMain class. Why should I not stop this?

Comment: OK, didn't see that.  Nope, won't shutdown because you have running threads.  You have to shutdown threads when they finish.

Comment: Please tell me how should I do that. What about multiple producers and consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have two threads, one should stop once `i == 10`.  The other thread is in an infinite loop though.  You need to signal to the consuming thread that the application should end. Look at the [Poison Pill](http://www.captaindebug.com/2013/03/producers-and-consumers-part-3-poison.html) as a way of telling the second thread to stop.

The program itself won't stop until that consuming thread completed.

Answer (score 0):

Removing while loop will cause consumer will consume only 1 object given by producer.

Better to go Excecuter framework. It is having Thread Factory and Thread Pool.You can use to implement the same.

Comment: Executor framework doesn't solve the OP's problem in this case.  OP wants to learn about threads and queues.  Purpose of executor framework is mainly to _hide_ threads and queues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to "fix" your code is to [make the consumer a daemon thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean))

```
Thread prod = new Thread(new Producer(obj));
Thread cons = new Thread(new Consumer(obj));

cons.setDaemon( true );
prod.start();
cons.start();
```

This really isn't a general solution, but a good trick to keep in mind when it's inconvenient to signal a thread to stop.

Comment: Nope.  The program will shut down immediately after the main method exists and the putting thread finishes.  If `i < 10` was `i < 100000` you would only get a handful that succeed.

Comment: Not after the main method: the producer has to exit too.  But yeah, threads are tricky, the consumer probably won't fully process the output.  Maybe I'll leave this up as a negative example...

Comment: OK for learning, but Bad Idea in general.  What if the consumer is writing to disk or communicating with some other process when the JVM abruptly terminates?  It would be better to tell the consumer that it's time to shut down, and maybe interrupt() it to be sure it gets the message in a timely fashion.